# appcenter-sdk-react-native AppCenterReactNative.h file not found on tvOS

Tags: react-native, tvos, appcenter

I am trying to add appcenter sdk to a react-native tvos app, but I get AppCenterReactNative.h file not found error when I add

```
#import <AppCenterReactNative.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.h>
```

I already did a pod install of course

Comment: Hello @Abdessamad,
Were you able to find a solution for this issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact issue when trying to integrate CodePush and AppCenter into my React Native app.

I followed the instructions to set up AppCenter, including adding the yarn/npm packages for AppCenter, and running `pod install`, but was getting this error that AppCenterReactNative.h couldn't be found.

I found this page, where the de
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-react-native/issues/713#issuecomment-534118574

I even verified in the `/Pods/Development Pods` folder that I had `appcenter-analytics`, `appcenter-core`, and `appcenter-crashes` in there. In `appcenter-core`, the `AppCenterReactNative.h` was right in there.

But Xcode still wasn't finding it.

Xcode wouldn't build or clean because of this. To fix this, I went and cleared my Derived Data. On the menu for Xcode, go to `Xcode -> Settings -> Derived Data (Click the small arrow with the path)`, then I deleted all the folders inside Derived Data, closed Xcode, re-opened it, and built the project, and it worked!

Hopefully this helps.